# how to enable Create git repository on mac in Xcode exist Project

Tags: xcode, git

hello I want to ask something when we create new Xcode project then I forgot to enable button Create git repository on my mac then how to enable this and how to add my code on SVN....for git is use ?

Comment: Your code is currently in SVN and you want to migrate to GIT?

Comment: yes I want to enable git

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and cd into the directory containing the .xcodeproj file

1.git init

2 In finder enter the newly created .git folder (in the same directory as the .xcodeproj file). Find info/exclude, open and add these lines, .DS_Store and xcuserdata/
Not sure if this is needed, but I used terminal to cp info/exclude over to a .gitignore file

3.git add .

4.git commit -m "Initial commit"

5.Now to get XCode to actually see the repo. In the project organizer, you first have to delete the project from the Projects tab. Then simply re-open the project to get it back. This will detect the GIT repository just created

In the repositories tab of the organizer I then branch off the master branch/switch into whatever version I'm working on.

Comment: Actually I don't know how to run terminal then from point 3 can you explain ....

Comment: go to Spotlight upper right corner of the desktop search terminal and click it..:)

Comment: I know I run terminal then direct drag my project folder then .....

Comment: Terminal Shows :Last login: Fri Oct 18 17:17:57 on ttys001
CC-DEV11:~ rahulsharma$ /Users/rahulsharma/Desktop/HIS_Project/HISWebService\ 11_oct 
-bash: /Users/rahulsharma/Desktop/HIS_Project/HISWebService 11_oct: is a directory
CC-DEV11:~ rahulsharma$

Comment: UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate this flie not found in my  project folder

Comment: @rahul i make some changes in my answer hope it will help you

Comment: I am in directory containing the .xcodeproj file, now for git init, it  says git command not found

Comment: for this you have to download git gui set up and install it

Comment: For 'git command not found' error - install command line tools (Xcode > Preferences > Downloads tab).